# coordinates string to int

Tags: java, string, integer, type-conversion

So I understand converting a String to int (parseInt, I know), but I was wondering if I could convert the following:

String coordinates = EasyIn.getString();
(e.g. "1, 1")

Integer.parseInt(coordinates); obviously doesn't work because there's more than one integer. Is there any way around this, or do I need to establish separate integers? Thanks for any advice or help on the matter!

(This is for Java, btw)

Comment: Do you know about the `split` method of the `String` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use newer APIs then do this:
First, find the comma with

```
int commaLoc = coordinates.indexOf(",");
```

Then parse each substring

```
int x = Integer.parseInt(coordinates.substring(0,commaLoc));
int y = Integer.parseInt(coordinates.substring(commaLoc + 2));
```

If you can then use a Scanner:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner (coordinates);
scanner.useDelimiter (", ");   
int x = scanner.nextInt();
int y = scanner.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct way in java, but it's just two simple lines if you use regex:

```
int x = Integer.parseInt(coordinates.replaceAll(",.*", ""));
int y = Integer.parseInt(coordinates.replaceAll(".*,", ""));
```

If you have java 8, it's one line to get an array of ints from a CSV of numbers.

```
int[] ints = Arrays.stream(coordinates.split(", *")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```